# How can I open links with python linux?

Tags: python, linux, google-chrome

I am on a chrome book that runs Chrome OS and Linux. I want to open youtube links randomly to make a party music picker. What do I install to do this?  have tried `webbrowser` and `urllib` but they both give me the following error, [error screen in linux.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FFUsu.png)

I have heard of the `selenium` and `youtube` modules and are wondering where I can find the docs for them?

Comment: Try using the `selenium` and `pytube` module.

Comment: Where can I find the docs?

Comment: [Pytube](https://pytube.io/en/latest/), [selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/)

Comment: see [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Please copy&paste the command you used and the error message *as text* to your question and format it as a code block.

Comment: Define "open". Open in a browser? Download?

Comment: I want to open the link in the chrome browser.